# print dataframe without losing format

Tags: python, pandas, printing, dataframe

How can I print a df without losing the format?

Lets say I have a df like this:

```
In: df
Out:

    TFs No Esenciales  Genes regulados  Genes Regulados Positivamente  Genes Regulados Negativamente  No Tentativo de genes a silenciar  No Real de genes a silenciar  No Tentativo de genes a inducir
146              YdeO               20                             18                              2                              2                               2                               0
```

But when I use print, It looses its format

```
In: print (df)
Out:
        TFs No Esenciales  Genes regulados  Genes Regulados Positivamente  \
146              YdeO               20                             18   

     Genes Regulados Negativamente  No Tentativo de genes a silenciar  \
146                              2                                 2   

     No Real de genes a silenciar  No Tentativo de genes a inducir  \
146                            2                               0   

     No Real de genes a inducir  Balance de genes  Balance real de genes  
146                          0                 2                      2
```

How can I use print, but keep the format?

My desired output is:

```
In: print (df)
    Out:

    TFs No Esenciales  Genes regulados  Genes Regulados Positivamente  Genes Regulados Negativamente  No Tentativo de genes a silenciar  No Real de genes a silenciar  No Tentativo de genes a inducir
146              YdeO               20                             18                              2                              2                               2                               0
```

Answer (score 1):

Per the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html), you can use the `display.width` option in Pandas.

Something like the following should work (although you may have to increase the `1000` width value if it's still getting cut-off).

```
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)
print(df)
```